# Create hourly count for multiple days with separate columns that each only has date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, hour

I have a server that contains a column with date only(datetime) and the other with time only(char), but I'm trying to create hourly counts with the code below but it's not showing up as expected:

```
    SELECT 
        account_date as Date,
        sum(qty) as qty
        sum(amount) as Amount,
        cast(datepart(hour,time) as varchar)
    FROM [data source]
    WHERE account_date between '10/1/2022' and '10/5/2022'
    GROUP BY account_date, time
```

I'm expecting something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAtba.png)

Here's the data format for date and time columns:

```
**Date**
2022-10-01 00:00:00.000
2022-10-02 00:00:00.000
2022-10-03 00:00:00.000
2022-10-04 00:00:00.000
**Time**
0709
0707
0707
0707
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: use [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a conditional aggregation or a PIVOT.

```
Select account_date
      ,[0000] = sum(case when HH='00' then qty else 0 end)
      ,[0100] = sum(case when HH='01' then qty else 0 end)
      ,[0200] = sum(case when HH='02' then qty else 0 end)
      -- ... add more columns
      ,[2300] = sum(case when HH='23' then qty else 0 end)
From   YourTable
Cross Apply ( values ( left([Time],2) ) ) B(HH)
Where  account_date between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-05'
Group By account_date
```

Comment: Hello John, thank you so much for your response! The format of the result looks good, but the sum of quantity for each hour of each date isn't correct. Do you know why that might be the case?